# Как сгенерировать случайное число в интервале без повторений?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Нужно сгенерировать случайное число в интервале от 1 до 30 включительно без повторений. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-sharp-set-collection

Comment: генерируете и добавляете в множество. Оно само уберёт дубликаты

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0 оригинал

Answer (score 1):

**Основная идея:** Записываем уникальные числа в список. Генерируем число от `0` до `N`, где `N` - *длина списка чисел*. После генерации **удаляем** из списка сгенерированное число.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).ToList();
    var numbersCopy = new List<int>(numbers);

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        var pickIndex = random.Next(numbersCopy.Count);
        var randNumber = numbersCopy[pickIndex];
        Console.WriteLine($"Generated value: {randNumber}");
        
        numbersCopy.RemoveAt(pickIndex);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

***Внимание***: Повторять такую генерацию можно до тех пор, пока числа не закончатся в списке. Далее необходимо будет заново создавать список чисел.

---

Написал класс, который генерирует числа без повторений до тех пор, пока они не закончатся, после чего по второму кругу генерирует эти же числа без повторений и т.д.

```
public class DistinctRandom
{
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
    private readonly int[] _numbers;
    private List<int> _notGeneratedNumbers;

    public DistinctRandom(int[] generateFrom)
    {
        _numbers = generateFrom;
        _notGeneratedNumbers = new List<int>(generateFrom);
    }

    public int Next()
    {
        if (!_notGeneratedNumbers.Any())
        {
            _notGeneratedNumbers = new List<int>(_numbers);
        }

        var pickIndex = _random.Next(_notGeneratedNumbers.Count);
        var randNumber = _notGeneratedNumbers[pickIndex];
        _notGeneratedNumbers.RemoveAt(pickIndex);
        return randNumber;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).ToArray();
    var distinctRandom = new DistinctRandom(numbers);

    var n = 50;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var randNumber = distinctRandom.Next();
        Console.WriteLine($"Generated number: {randNumber}");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Тасование Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)

```cs
Random random = new Random();
int n = 30;
int[] array = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < n; n++)
{
    int j = random.Next(n);
    int x = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = x;
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
```

Вывод

```
5 24 16 1 8 17 14 23 12 9 7 21 2 11 4 30 28 10 13 29 3 25 20 6 15 18 22 19 26 27
```