# Как удалить повторения в выводе, не прибегая к еще одному циклу?

Tags: c#, массивы

Данный код создает 6 случайных чисел и записывает их в массив, после чего чистит его от повторений, но бывает такое, что повторений больше чем 2 и код повторно выводит это значение. Как я могу вывести повторения, как бы это смешно не звучало, без повторений?

```
Random num = new Random();
            int[] Values = new int[6];
            for (int i = 0; i < Values.Length; i++)
            {
                Values[i] = num.Next(10);
            }
            Array.Sort(Values);

            for (int i = 1; i < Values.Length; i++)
            {
                if(Values[i]==Values[i-1])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Values[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сгенерировать случайное число в интервале без повторений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212298/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko я думаю более корректно будет это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547996/191482

Comment: Мне не нужен массив без повторений, мне как раз и нужно вывести повторения

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну вот я как раз не согласен с тем, что вопрос, который указал я, является дубликатом того вопроса, который указали вы. Все же здесь вопрос о создании случайной последовательности чисел без повторений, а не о случайном перемешивании уже существующего массива чисел

Comment: Использовать HashSet<int>

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Lono понял, отозвал голос на закрытие

Comment: @AK Распишите подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: @Lono вы совершенно неправильно ищете повторения. Вам нужен `HashSet<int>`, чтобы проверять числа на повторения

Comment: Написал подробнее в поле ответ - в комментариях неудобно код давать. Возможно, алгоритм не самый оптимальный по памяти, упор на one pass traversal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как я могу вывести повторения, как бы это смешно не звучало, без повторений?
>
> Мне не нужен массив без повторений, мне как раз и нужно вывести повторения

```
void Main()
{
    var nums = new[] {1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,7};
    GetDupes(nums).Dump();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

public int[] GetDupes(int[] nums)
{
    var dict = new HashSet<int>();
    var result = new HashSet<int>();
    
    foreach (var item in nums)
    {
        if(dict.Contains(item))
            result.Add(item);
        else
            dict.Add(item);
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

> Как удалить повторения в выводе, не прибегая к еще одному циклу?

Если отвечать именно на этот вопрос, то код, решающий конкретную задачу автора, следующий:

```
Random num = new Random();
int[] Values = new int[6];
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < Values.Length; i++)
{
    Values[i] = num.Next(10);
    if (hashSet.Add(Values[i]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Values[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Формально - да, но этот код имеет на мой взгляд один существенный недостаток. Ещё в школе учат разделять ввод данных (генерацию), расчёт и вывод данных. И поскольку в школе это слабо осознаётся как правильная практика -- то потом люди приходят в профессию и не понимают ни в архитектуру программы, ни понимают, где они нарушают SPR и с трудом въезжают в чистые функции.

Comment: @AK я понимаю вашу критику и принимаю ее. Но что если мы говорим об олимпиадном программировании и здесь важна эффективность кода? Улучшать читабельность и соблюдать принципы ООП в жертву еще одного пробега по массиву, в таком случае (как мне кажется), будет неуместно.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: `HashSet<T>.Add` возвращает статус добавления, поэтому немного изящнее было бы `if (hashSet.Add(Values[i])) Console.WriteLine(Values[i]);`

Comment: @VladD согласен. Совсем забыл об этой особенности. Спасибо, поправил!

Answer (score 0):

Используя HashSet я решил следующим образом не прибегая к List и к Linq в целом

```
Random num = new Random();
int[] Values = new int[6];
for (int i = 0; i < Values.Length; i++)
{
    Values[i] = num.Next(10);
}

HashSet<int> povt = new HashSet<int>();

for (int i = 1; i < Values.Length; i++)
{
    if(Values[i]==Values[i-1])
    {
        povt.Add(Values[i]);
    }
}
foreach (int pov in povt)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pov);
}
```

Comment: Вы не очень понимаете HashSet'ы: это видно по тому, что вы оставили сортировку массива. Она не нужна, только замедляет программу, т.к. даёт нагрузку n log n в среднем (а то и n ^ 2). Вы конечно вольны поставить себе галку, но вернитесь к этой задаче через полгода - год, возможно увидите, что не так с ответом. Возможно, вы и хотели решением сместить tradeoff между скоростью и памятью, но как-то не особо удачно на мой взгляд.

Comment: Можете убрать массив вообще. И добавлять в HashSet рандомные числа, пока там не будет 6 элементов. Вернуть потом этот HashSet потребителю как IReadOnlyCollection<int>

Comment: @AK Вы несомненно правы, я устраню у себя данные недостатки, большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А в такой форме (без сортировки) решение становится нерабочим. :) Поэтому либо sort & walk с одним хешсетом, либо без сортировки - и тогда нужен один хешсет под поиск дублей и ещё одна структура (другой hashset) под итоговый результат.