# как пермешать рандомно массив

Tags: c#

Не совсем понял правильно ли я реализовал метод шафла карт Нашел в интеренете шафлы попробывал реализовать получилось как то так  так же как после этого шафла вывести первую карту с колоды буду рад если кто то обьяснит правильно ли я реализовал Шафл и поможет вывести мне этот результат шафла в коде с обьяснением
namespace

```
  public class Deck : Card
    {
        private readonly Card[] _cards = new Card[52];
        public Deck() 
        {
            int y = 0;
            foreach (var rank in Card.Ranks)
            {
                foreach (var suit in Card.Suits)
                {
                    _cards[y] = new Card(rank, suit);
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void Shaffle() /// метод шафла
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = _cards.Length - 1; i >= 1 ; i--)
            {
               
                int j = random.Next(i + 1);
        
                var tmp = _cards[j];
                _cards[j] = _cards[i];
                _cards[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
        public void TakeCard( ) /// Тут нужно вывести уже как пользователь берет за шафленую карту 
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        
    }
    namespace Lesson_20.Classes;
    
    public class Card
    {
    
     public static readonly string[] Ranks = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
     public static readonly string[] Suits = { "\u2660 ", "\u2665 ", "\u2666 ", "\u2663 " };
     private readonly string _rank;
     private readonly string _suit;
    
     public Card(string rank, string suit)
     {
      _rank = rank;
      _suit = suit;
     }
    
     protected Card()
     {
     
     }
    
     public override string ToString()
     {
      return $"{_rank}{_suit}";
     }
    }
    

namespace Lesson_20;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.TakeCard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ищите "Фишер-Йейтс".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1212504/373567

Comment: @aepot спасибо насколько я понял что я правильно прописал шафл если судить по вашей теме которую вы скинули и которую я нашел в интеренете благодарю вас